# How to localize formio components in formsflow.ai?

Tags: formsflow.ai

Attaching screenshot of the same here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1ZTc.png)

Expecting a way to apply localization in formio components for user-specific accessibility.

Comment: Refer this link [formio translation](https://help.form.io/developers/translations)